# MyFaces Test Framework not working with JSF 2.1

Tags: jsf-2, junit4

we have a lot of tests that uses Myfaces Test Framework for JSF 2.0.
http://myfaces.apache.org/test/index.html

Problem is we can't get it to work with JSF 2.1. Does anyone know a workaround or a way to solve this?

When we run the tests we get the following error: `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Application was not properly initialized at startup, could not find Factory: javax.faces.application.ApplicationFactory`

It works fine with jsf 2.0 though.

A typical use case in our code:

```
// code block;
assertFalse("Error message not expected. ", facesContext
            .getMessages().hasNext());
```

JSF 2.1 has a few syntax changes so my guess would be that's the problem.

Answer (score 0):

MyFaces Test 2.0 works with 2.0 and 2.1. In fact, MyFaces 2.1 uses myfaces-test20-1.0.4 as test dependency, and inside the code you can find a lot of tests using that library.